# A/C stops blowing cold when it's raining

Tags: chevrolet, ac, equinox

I have a 2011 equinox. Had a accident couple years ago involved with front end. Ever since then when it rains my AC will stop blowing cold air. never heard of anything like this. anyone have any explanations? Plz help

Comment: Did they miss a damaged sensor? Chaffed wires on the temperature sensor...

Comment: Does it really stop completely? Cooling very wet air, as in rain, costs much more power, so cooling performance is lower. If the AC has lost some power, it might seem as if it does not cool at all.

Comment: Along the lines of what @sweber is saying, you may want to test the air temp when it's running "normally" to see what it's at. It may be it's not functioning at capacity when it appears to be working.

Comment: THE A/C DOESN'T STOP JUST COLD AIR

Answer (score 2):

High humidity can condense then freeze on the evaporator coils more readily than dry air. This blocks the air flow . To avoid this keep fan on high with all vents open. Possibly, from the accident, there is some distortion to a vent that restricts air flow, to or from the coils.

Answer (score 0):

"Rainy" air contains more water, which is harder to cool, so your system may no longer be able to keep up with the cooling requirements during wet weather.  Your accident maybe have damaged some of your AC components—my suspicion would be you have a refrigerant leak.  I would recommend having the system vacuum-tested to confirm that it actually holds pressure.